# How to allow your app with usage access?

Tags: android, android-permissions

From android lollipop, the app that wants to access usage of other apps needs to be enabled by security. Rather than manually enabling it manually by Settings -> Security -> Apps with usage access, I want to enable it programmatically. I cannot find a clear answer anywhere. Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


private boolean isAccessGranted() {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
        return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code i hope help you

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 10, time);

        if (stats == null || stats.isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest

**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"**

and continue with this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278489/16126283